# autorun script doesn't work when logout and then login

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, cx-freeze, linux-mint, cinnamon

After using cx_Freeze to freeze my Python scripts into executables,the executable file named BingNiceWallpapers.
I want it to autorun when logging in,so write this script named BingNiceWallpapers.desktop putted it in ~/.config/autorun

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/home/i/图片/build/exe.linux-i686-3.4/BingNiceWallpapers
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name[zh_CN]=BingNiceWallpapers
Name=BingNiceWallpapers
Comment[zh_CN]=
Comment=
X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=0
```

The problem is when boot or reboot the computer, the program does autorun when logging in,but when logout and then login with the same account, the program  doesn't autorun, so how to fix this issue ?

I tested on linuxmint-17.1-cinnamon-32bit

Comment: There should be no need to freeze it - you can use a Python script as an executable on Linux. It doesn't sound like that's the issue you're having, though

Comment: @ThomasK The reason why I freeze it is that I want to create closed source software.

Comment: It's probably not as obfuscated as you think, but that's another issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to do the same on **linuxmint-17.1-cinnamon-32bit** . I made executable and put it into `~/bin` folder. Then I added my application to startup via GUI (I only specified **Name** and **Command** in dialog box). And checked whether application runs after logging out and then logging in: it runs.

So the configuration file `myapp.desktop` looks like the following:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/home/me/bin/myapp
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name[en_US]=MyApp
Name=MyApp
Comment[en_US]=
Comment=
X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=0
```

And it is located in `~/.config/autostart` folder (but not in `autorun`).